# How does one say "annoying" in Esperanto?

Tags: single-word-requests

Since the word *ĝeni* means "to bother, to annoy", what would annoying be? (Ex: She is so annoying)

Would it be *ĝenanta* or *ĝena*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Ĝena* can be used as an equivalent to *ĝenanta*. However, *ĝeni* means "to hinder" and by extension, "to bother, distract." In the *Plena Ilustrita Vortaro*, the definitions are:

> 1 *Malfaciligi aŭ malhelpi ies movojn* To make someone's movements more difficult
>
> 2 *Malfaciligi ies agojn, pensojn ktp per ne materiala malhelpo* To make someone's acts or thoughts more difficult by non-material means

Therefore, strictly speaking, *ĝenanta* means "bothersome" in the sense of hindering, or distracting.

If they are not getting in the way, or distracting, then you could try ***iritanta*** ("irritating"). So I would suggest ***Ŝi iritas min (tiom).***

Related words are *ĉagrenanta* ("upsetting, vexing"), *incitanta* ("teasing"), *tedanta* ("boring, over-persistent, repetitious").

The commenter 2_K_ suggests ***agaca***, which I forgot about completely.

Comment: What about *agaca*? I see *agaca* / *agaci* being used in the sense of "irritating, annoying", and although dictionaries often always give "tart, acerbic" as one of the translations to English, Esperanto already has "acida" for the taste. This is a  text from Claude Piron: 

La soldato kiu marŝas

en la vento

en silento

sur la vojo kiu marĉas

sian korpon ne plu sentas.



Lia menso fakte brutas,

nur la laco

kaj l' agaco

de la pluvo kiu gutas

senkompate lin turmentas.

Comment: That's a good one. You should post it as an answer.

Comment: Could you add it to your answer as an additional option?

Comment: Ok. I have edited.

Answer (score 2):

The adjective form of *ĝeni* is *ĝena*.

The word *ĝenanta* is, of course, possible, but you'll rarely find it used as an adjective, which is what you're asking.

More often, *ĝenanta* is used to show action:

- li ne estos ĉiam ĝenanta kaj muĝanta (he won't be always getting in the way and grumbling.)
- [ŝia koro] volus disŝiri la tunikon, ĝenantan la bruston.

A person who is habitually annoying could be called *ĝenema*.

Comment: What about ĝenema?

Comment: Sounds good. I've added it to my answer. Thanks.